# Correcting the background of an image capture of the monitor screen

Tags: image-processing, filtering

I have an image (that I camera-captured the monitor screen) and I would like to filter the background. The photo seems to contain flickers and a lot of background noise. I need to remove the noise as I would like to proceed with edge detection.

[image]
I have tried these methods ( [1](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/images/ipexrice.html) and [2](http://makarandtapaswi.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/census-transform-and-faces/)), but I still cannot get a clean background. What should be the proper method to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try local adaptive thresholding. [This](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8647-local-adaptive-thresholding) is a good implementation for Matlab.

Comment: Thank you Diana! 
Here is what I observed after trying the suggested code (after removing the thresholding + BW conversion lines) : 

ws = 49; C = 0.04; 
1. the scan lines and ringing still exist 
2. The background local illumination is has been adjusted  
3. The objects within the bag (with low saturation and low intensity) are not visible. 

I have also tried with a larger window size, ws at 95, and the three conditions above are still observed.